# Service Activity Crashing in Background

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, service

I am working on a simple Service application which increments a counter ever 1 second and shows notification after every 10 seconds. I have used thread so, when I close my app service runs in the background.

Problem- Everything is working fine but when I immediately press back button after starting the counter on button click. My App crashes. Can somebody tell me what is the problem? Thanks!

```
public class MyService extends Service {
        private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 5453;
        String s;
        boolean flag=true;
        int cooo;
        int m;
        int n=0;

       private void triggerNotification(final int text){   //Notification Triggering Function
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_noti);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceActivity.class);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(ServiceActivity.class);   // Creates a virtual stack so that when back key is pressed main activity will be displayed
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );
                Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                CharSequence tickerText="Current Counter Value :"+text;
                Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setLargeIcon(bm)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_noti)             // Setting Notification Icon
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification))                // Setting Title of Notification
                        .setAutoCancel(true)                               // Makes this notification automatically dismissed when the user touches it
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)           // Setting priority to Max
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setContentText(tickerText)
                        .setLights(0xFF0000FF, 100,3000)
                        .setSound(soundUri)
                        .build();

                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                NotificationManager notificationManager =                        //Notification Manager
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                // Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");

            }
        @Nullable
        @Override


        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        } //Default function of service class

        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID){ //Function recieving intent from startService

            cooo=intent.getIntExtra("cont", 0);
            s=Integer.toString(cooo);
            Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() { //Thread Initialized
                    while(flag){
                       try{ Log.d("The counter value is:", s + " ");
                        m=Integer.parseInt(s);
                        m++;
                           n++;
                        s=Integer.toString(m);

                           if(n%10==0){
                               Log.d("Notification Triggered", "Congrats!");
                               triggerNotification(m);
                           }

                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start(); //Thread Started
            return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startID); //sending intent again
        }

        public void onDestroy(){ //function call on stop button pressed
            super.onDestroy();
            flag=false;
            Log.d("Notification Triggered","on stop Button");
            triggerNotification(m);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

> Error Log-
>
> 04-06 23:06:11.450 16940-16940/headfirst.com.serviceapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service
>   headfirst.com.serviceapplication.MyService@427724e8 with null:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2850)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:159)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                         at
>   headfirst.com.serviceapplication.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:72)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2833)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:159) 
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
>                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please paste crash logs.

Comment: have you declared your service in manifest file? @codingrocks

Comment: @KiranKumar Yes, I have defined my service class there. The problem is if I immediately press back button on my phone & close the app, the thread stops after some seconds otherwise it is working fine.

Comment: Can Someone help me please?

Comment: Please paste the code where you are starting your service.